# load google maps iframe after jquery append

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have this nice iframe 3d view in google map in a file called iframe.php

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1sen!2shk!4v1484532774391!6m8!1m7!1sOYCSnR8N9qoAAAQ7LsT_ew!2m2!1d22.27612005902588!2d114.1724398834276!3f285!4f0!5f0.7820865974627469" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I want to load this after ajax in an specific div when the customer click a button

```
<a href="#">Load iframe</a>
<div id="iframe">
</div>

<script>
$(document).on('click','a',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'iframe.php'
  }).done(function(iframe) {
    $('#iframe').append(iframe);
  });
});
</script>
```

But this loads the html (show me plain text) and the iframe does not run. What am I missing? or the iframe can only run onload?

Answer (score 2):

Try .html(...) instead of .append(...)

This code works for youtube video:

```
<div id="frame"></div>
<button id="btn-clickable">Clicke Me!</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#btn-clickable', function () {
            $('#frame').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U2SRUPbtVWQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check out the code. For the youtube video it works fine... Are you getting string in return? Maybe logging it will solve the problem. See what you are getting in return.

Comment: I can not use html...because it delete the content of #iframe div... but now is working, as you said was an error in the iframe element